# error: calling a __host__ function from a __global__ function is not allowed

Tags: cuda

I have written cuda function for dense sampling of feature points but i am getting error. My cuda code is given below. I am using cuda 7.5 toolkit.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace cv::gpu;
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

__global__ void densefun(std::vector<int>* d_counters,std::vector<Point2f>* d_points,int d_x_max,int d_y_max,int width, int min_distance)
{
  int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  Point2f point = (*d_points)[i];
  int x = cvFloor(point.x);
  int y = cvFloor(point.y);
  //if(x >= d_x_max || y >= d_y_max)
      //continue;
  x /= min_distance;
  y /= min_distance;
  (*d_counters)[y*width+x]++;
}


void dense(std::vector<int>& counters,std::vector<Point2f>& points,int x_max,int y_max,int width)
{
  std::vector<int>* d_counters;
  std::vector<Point2f>* d_points;
  int min_distance=5; 
  cudaMalloc(&d_counters,counters.size());
  cudaMalloc(&d_points,points.size());
  cudaMemcpy(d_points, &points, points.size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  densefun<<<1,points.size()>>>(d_counters,d_points,x_max,y_max,width,min_distance);
  cudaMemcpy(&counters, d_counters, counters.size(), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree(d_counters);
  cudaFree(d_points);
}
```

Output:

> /home/supriya/Desktop/5Dec/CalculateFV_merged_gpu_old/build/denseCuda.cu(28):
>   error: calling a **host** function("cv::Point_ ::Point_") from
>   a **global** function("densefun") is not allowed
>
> /home/supriya/Desktop/5Dec/CalculateFV_merged_gpu_old/build/denseCuda.cu(28):
>   error: calling a **host** function("std::vector ,
>   std::allocator > > ::operator []") from a **global**
>   function("densefun") is not allowed
>
> /home/supriya/Desktop/5Dec/CalculateFV_merged_gpu_old/build/denseCuda.cu(29)
>   (col. 7): error: calling a **host** function("cvFloor") from a
>   **global** function("densefun") is not allowed
>
> /home/supriya/Desktop/5Dec/CalculateFV_merged_gpu_old/build/denseCuda.cu(30)
>   (col. 7): error: calling a **host** function("cvFloor") from a
>   **global** function("densefun") is not allowed
>
> /home/supriya/Desktop/5Dec/CalculateFV_merged_gpu_old/build/denseCuda.cu(35):
>   error: calling a **host** function("std::vector > ::operator []") from a **global**
>   function("densefun") is not allowed
>
> 5 errors detected in the compilation of
>   "/tmp/tmpxft_00000c85_00000000-7_denseCuda.cpp1.ii". CMake Error at
>   testVideo_generated_denseCuda.cu.o.cmake:260 (message):   Error
>   generating file
>   /home/supriya/Desktop/5Dec/CalculateFV_merged_gpu_old/build/CMakeFiles/testVideo.dir//./testVideo_generated_denseCuda.cu.o
>
> CMakeFiles/testVideo.dir/build.make:392: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/testVideo.dir/./testVideo_generated_denseCuda.cu.o' failed
>   make[2]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/testVideo.dir/./testVideo_generated_denseCuda.cu.o] Error
>   1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:130: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/testVideo.dir/all' failed make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/testVideo.dir/all] Error 2 Makefile:76: recipe for target
>   'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use C++ standard library, OpenCV or any other non-CUDA specific library inside a CUDA kernel.

Instead of `std::vector` you need to use raw pointers to arrays allocated on the device, instead of `Point2f` you need to use CUDA specific vector type `float2`, instead of `cvFloor` you need to use `__device__ ​ floorf()` and so on.