# Error: an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I had asked doubt [error: calling a __host__ function from a __global__ function is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440428/error-calling-a-host-function-from-a-global-function-is-not-allowed/41440734#41440734) and i got the ans . accordingly i have modified my code bt i am unable to access d_point[i]. how can i access that.

```
  __global__ void densefun(int *d_counters,float2 *d_points,int d_x_max,int d_y_max,int width,int height, int min_distance,int size)
{
  int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

   if(i <= size)
   {
        float2 point = (d_points)[i];
        int x = floorf(point.x);
        int y = floorf(point.y);
        printf(" ( %d  %d )",x,y);
        if(x < d_x_max && y < d_y_max)
        {  
            x /= min_distance;
            y /= min_distance;
            (d_counters)[y*width+x]++;
            __syncthreads();
        }
    }
}


void DenseSample(const Mat& grey, std::vector<Point2f>& points, const double quality, const int min_distance)
{
    int width = grey.cols/min_distance;
    int height = grey.rows/min_distance;
    Mat eig;
    cornerMinEigenVal(grey, eig, 3, 3);
    double maxVal = 0;
    minMaxLoc(eig, 0, &maxVal);
    const double threshold = maxVal*quality;
    std::vector<int> counters(width*height);
    int x_max = min_distance*width;
    int y_max = min_distance*height; 
    printf("in descriptor size:%ld ",points.size());   
    int *d_counters;
    float2 *d_points;
    cudaMalloc(&d_counters,counters.size()*width*height*sizeof(int));
    printf("in cuda point size:%d       ",points.size());
    cudaMalloc(&d_points,points.size()*sizeof(float2));
    cout<<"points.size() : "<<points.size()<<endl;
    cudaMemcpy(d_points, &points, points.size()*sizeof(float2), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int blk=cvFloor(points.size()/1024)+1;
    cout<<"blk : "<<blk<<endl;
    if(points.size()>0)
    {
        densefun<<<blk,1024>>>(d_counters,d_points,x_max,y_max,width,height,min_distance, points.size());
        cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
        if (err != cudaSuccess) 
        printf("Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        cudaMemcpy(&counters, d_counters, counters.size()* width*height*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }
    cudaFree(d_counters);
    cudaFree(d_points);
    points.clear();
    int index = 0;
    int offset = min_distance/2;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++, index++) 
    {
        if(counters[index] <= 0)
        {
            int x = j*min_distance+offset;
            int y = i*min_distance+offset;
            if(eig.at<float>(y, x) > threshold)
            points.push_back(Point2f(float(x), float(y)));
        }
    }
}
```

output is:
in descriptor size:1605       in cuda point size:1605       points.size() : 1605

blk : 2
Error: an illegal memory access was encountered
in descriptor size:918       in cuda point size:918       points.size() : 918

blk : 1
Error: an illegal memory access was encountered

Comment: How do you know that access of d_points is actually the cause of the problem?

Comment: I assume you want to check if `x` and `y` need to be within constraints of respectively `d_x_max` and `d_y_max`. Shouldn't `if(x < d_x_max || y < d_y_max)` be `if(x < d_x_max && y < d_y_max)` then?

Comment: Access of d_points is the cause of problem because i tried to print value of x and y it does not get printed .I tried if(x < d_x_max && y < d_y_max)   but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

You create a thread gird with block length `1024` and grid length equal to

`int blk=cvFloor(points.size()/1024)+1;`

Which basically means that the number of threads will be multiple of 1024 greater than `points.size()`.  In this case using:

```
int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
float2 point = (d_points)[i];
```

cannot be successful, because you can be almost certain that you will get out of bounds memory access. Add some conditional to ensure that it won't happen.

```
__global__ void densefun(int *d_counters,float2 *d_points,int d_x_max,int d_y_max,int width, int height, int min_distance)
{
  int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  if(i < width * height)
  {
      //rest of the code
  }

}
```

Also, you don't allocate enugh memory for `d_points`:

```
float2 *d_points;

cudaMalloc(&d_points,points.size()*sizeof(float));
```

If you want to allocate array of `float2` (or copy to it) you need to use `sizeof(float2)`.

Comment: Sorry about the edit, I misunderstood what you were trying to say around the code block.

Comment: Thank you for ans. it was useful . Adding condition works but only for first iteration in the next iteration same problem occurs.

Comment: You also don't allocate enough memory for `d_points`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to current version ?

Comment: Can you make this code readable ? Come on man, people are trying to help you here, you might put some effort and make code not look like a mess.

Comment: Use weak comparison in `if(i <= size)`. Also,  you don't need to call `_syncthreads()`. And last, If you're using printf in kernel, you need to call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after invoking the kernel.

Comment: what do you mean by weak comparison? I don't understand.

Comment: I mean using `<` instead of  `<=`.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Well, you might as well update the code in question.