# How to convince CMake to use the CUDA fmax function instead of the std cmath function?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, c++14

Say I have the following function:

```
__global__ void testFunction(double *a, double *b) {
   unsigned int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   a[index] = fmax(b[index], 0.0f);
}
```

then building gives the error:

> error: calling a constexpr __host__ function("fmax") from a __global__ function("testFunction") is not allowed. The experimental flag '--expt-relaxed-constexpr' can be used to allow this.

This [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440428/error-calling-a-host-function-from-a-global-function-is-not-allowed/41440734) means that I cannot use the function fmax, which is defined in the std library cmath. However, it is also defined as [a CUDA device function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1g8f5b0627e6706e432728bd16cb326754), which is the one I wanted to use in the first place.

So the question is: how to tell CMake (or any compiler if that's an option) to use the CUDA __device__ definition of fmax instead of the std cmath version?

Note: I am ***not*** using `using namespace std;` and/or `#include < cmath>` in this code.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(NAME CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(NAME main.cu /*some other files*/)

set_target_properties(
        NAME
        PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

Comment: Is the CUDA function not namespaced? Followup, this is nvcc giving you the error?

Comment: The problem is the arguments to the function. you are trying to call fmax(double, float). That doesn't exist in the CUDA math library

Comment: So switch your `0.0f` constant to `0.0` The function prototype you are using is `(double)fmax(double, double)`

Comment: @talonmies and Robert-Crovella thank you, that fixed it! :D (I may only tag one person rip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with CMake or linking.

CUDA uses template overloading to provide native math library functions in device code. As per the documentation, exactly two versions of `fmax` are provided ([here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_1g8f5b0627e6706e432728bd16cb326754) and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1g6e7516db46be25c33fb26e203287f2a3)). They are

```
float fmax(float, float)
double fmax(double double)
```

Your code is requesting

```
double fmax(double, float)
```

because `0.0f` is a single precision constant. There is no native overload for that, so it falls through the CUDA toolchain front end and the compiler winds up concluding you want a host function, thus the error.

The correct code would be

```
a[index] = fmax(b[index], 0.);
```

That will use the correct double precision version.